# No mapping exists from ObjectParameter to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, wcf, entity-framework

I am in the process of building a WCF service using EF to a Microsoft SQL Server but keep getting the following error:

> Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter to a known managed provider native type.

On this query:

```
string ID = "XXID";
string Sql = @"SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE " + ID + " LIKE '@SearchTerm'";
ObjectParameter[] Parameters = new ObjectParameter[2];
Parameters[0] = new ObjectParameter("Table", Table);
Parameters[1] = new ObjectParameter("SearchTerm", SearchTerm);

using (var Context = new XXEntities())
{
    Context.Database.Connection.Open();
    IEnumerable<string> Query = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(Sql, Parameters);

    string[] Results = Query.ToArray();
    Context.Database.Connection.Close();
    return Results; 
}
```

I have tested the query on SQL Server and it works as expected- returning the record of a matched ID.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try using sql parameter instaed of object parameter

```
IEnumerable<string> Query = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(Sql, 
new SqlParameter("Table", Table), 
new SqlParameter("SearchTerm", SearchTerm));
```

Theoretically  you can manipulate sql without the need of any send in parameters like this

```
IEnumerable<string> Query = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT * FROM "+Table+" WHERE " + ID + " LIKE '"+SearchTerm+"'");
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to SqlParameters but now get the following error: "The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types." ??

Comment: Thanks. I just remembered that I have had the new error before its because the data is not compatible with an array. Back to the original error can I ask what the difference is between ObjectParameter and SqlParameter? Thanks Again.

Comment: If you call store-procedure thru EF you will pass object parameter in your case you ding sql so you pass sql

Comment: Do not do the second string concatenation way.  It is susceptible to SQL Injection which is the whole point of using parameters.